# Smallest graph coloring in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi, graphs

I am trying to design an algorithm to label a graph’s nodes with as few colors as possible
such that all pairs of nodes joined by an edge do not have the same color.

This is the code I have written so far. I have added the variables x[0] to x[n-1] for the graph's nodes. I do not understand how to add the constraint that for each set of connected nodes (0 and 1; 1 and 2; and 1 and 3) the colors may not be equal. Subject to these constraints the goal is to find the minimize the maximum c_i (the color of a node) where all colors are nonnegative integers. You cannot directly add an inequality constraint in Gurobi or a Boolean constraint that if nodes i and j are connected then c_i <= c_j - 1 or c_i >= c_j + 1. Can anyone suggest an approach to do this?

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum

n = 4 
N = [i for i in range(n)]

edges = [[1], [2, 3], [], []] #node 0 is connected to node 1; and 1 is connected to 2 and 3 

mdl = Model('CVRP') 

x = mdl.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.INTEGER) #x (node color) is a nonnegative integer 

mdl.modelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE 
 
mdl.addConstrs(x[i] >= 0 for i in range(n))  
 
mdl.optimize()
mdl.display()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that choice of variables, you can use a constraint programming solver, together with, for each edge, either a *disequality* or an *alldiff* constraint to enforce a proper coloring.

The usual integer linear programming approach for graph coloring is to instead use binary decision variable $x_{ic}$ to indicate whether node $i\in N$ is assigned color $c\in C$ and binary decision variable $y_c$ to indicate whether color $c$ is ever used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{c\in C} y_c$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{c\in C} x_{ic} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in N$} \tag1\label1 \\
x_{ic} + x_{jc} &\le y_c &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$ and $c\in C$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns exactly one color to each node.
Constraint \eqref{2} prevents assigning $i$ and $j$ the same color $c$ if $(i,j)$ is an edge, and it also enforces the logical implication $(x_{ic} \lor x_{jc}) \implies y_c$ to properly record that color $c$ is used.  You could also impose $x_{ic} \le y_c$ to handle any isolated nodes, but you might as well just preprocess any such nodes away by fixing $x_{i1}=1$ and $y_1=1$.

You can take $C=\{1,\dots,|N|\}$ or, more generally, $C=\{1,\dots,u\}$, where $u\le |N|$ is an upper bound on the number of colors needed.  Such an upper bound can be obtained by any proper (perhaps greedy) coloring.

The problem is symmetric with respect to $c$, and an application of Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition with one block per $c$ leads to a set partitioning master problem with identical blocks, which can be solved via column generation with Ryan-Foster branching.  This approach is [automated in SAS](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_037/casmopt/casmopt_decomp_details06.htm), or you can implement a specialized algorithm as in [Mehrotra and Trick (1996)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoc.8.4.344).  Relaxing \eqref{1} to $\ge 1$ can sometimes improve the performance of this approach.